# Is there a difference between undefined and unaffected behavior for flags?

Tags: assembly, x86

Some sources I looked at listed some flags behavior as undefined for some instructions, while different sources list unaffected.  I know that undefined behavior of flags shouldn't be looked at, but what about unaffected behavior?  Are they the same things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they are not the same thing.

Unaffected means exactly what it says. It will not change the value of the flags register.

Undefined behavior means that the architecture can do whatever it wants with the flags register.

Comment: If the flags are unaffected, then that means you can use a branch after one or more instructions that do not affect the flags to take a branch based on the last instruction that did affect the flags.